# Parsing daterange param as two attributes - Rails 4, Datetimepicker GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetimepicker

I have a model `Foo` with two `datetime` attributes called `start_time` and `end_time`. `Foo` has a validation logic for each attribute:

#### Model:

```
...
validate :dates_logic_validation, on: :save
...
  def dates_logic_validation
    if start_time < Time.now
      errors.add(:start_time, 'Start time must be greater or equal to today\'\s date')
      return false
    elsif start_time > end_time
      errors.add(:end_time, 'End time must be greater than start time')
      return false
    else
      true
    end
  end
```

The validation error handling works fine when I try to create / update `Foo` via the console. Using [datetimepicker gem](https://github.com/jordanbrock/bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails), I am getting both dates in params hash. In my `foos#create`, I want to be able to parse this `daterange` param and assign it `foo.start_time` and `foo.end_time`. To do so, I added an instance method:

```
  def parse_date_range(daterange) #<= param is passed as "12/02/2015 - 01/14/2016"
    start_time = daterange.split("-")[0].strip!
    end_time = daterange.split("-")[1].strip!
    update_attributes(start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time)
  end
```

then calling it like so:

#### Controller (#create):

```
  def create
    @foo= Foo.new(foo_params)
    @foo.parse_date_range(params[:daterange])
    if @foo.valid?
      @foo.save
      redirect_to foos_path(@foo)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

and here is where the music stops. If I log `#{start_time}` and `#{end_time}` after I call `parse_data_range` on `@foo`, both will be empty. Which suggests that I probably can't call `update_attributes` on a non-existing object. If that's the case, what would be the best solution?

Comment: param is having just date, no time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a mistake to do a second database query (`update_attributes`) when instead you can extract the dates from `params` in the controller like this:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :extract_start_end_times, only: :create

  def create
    @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)

    if @foo.valid?
      @foo.save
      redirect_to foos_path(@foo)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...

  private
  def extract_start_end_times
    return unless params[:daterange].present?
    daterange = params.delete(:daterange)

    start_time, end_time = daterange.split(/\s*-\s*/)
                             .map {|date| Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') }

    params.merge!(start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time)
  end
end
```

Note the use of `Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')`. This is necessary because your dates are in an ambiguous format (Ruby has no way to know if "12/02/2015" is Dec. 2 or Feb. 12).

If you're using strong parameters you may have to modify your `foo_params` method to accommodate the `start_time` and `end_time` params.

Answer (score 0):

This should get to work.

```
update_attributes(start_time: Date.parse(start_time), end_time: Date.parse(end_time))
```

You can also use

```
DateTime.parse("12/02/2015")
=> Thu, 12 Feb 2015 00:00:00 +0000
```